# EF changeTracker not giving Proper value

Tags: entity-framework, change-tracking

Hi I am using EF5 DataBase First. And using Change Tracker to track the Modified element. One of My Requirement is:
RowA
RowB
If I Change Value of RowB "RowB should be disable and RowC should be created".[WorkingFine]

```
                var rowC = CreateEntityObjectBySelectedTableName(selectedDataTable);
                rowC.IsActiveRecord = true;
                context.Context.XYZTypes.Add(rowC);
                context.Context.Entry(rowC).State = EntityState.Added;
                changedEntity.CurrentValues.SetValues(changedEntity.OriginalValues);//for RowB business Req
                rowB.IsActiveRecord = false;//To disable RowB business Req
```

Problem: Now if I change RowC The change Tracker is Giving me Still RowB as Modified state not RowC. Thanks in Advance!!
The Above Code Snippet Work Fine in First Iteration. but later try again doing it My DBContext has rowB as Modified not RowC.

Comment: "RowB should be disable" <--- would you elaborate? A code snippet or something like that would be helpful as well.

Comment: var changedEntities = Context.ChangeTracker.Entries().Where(x => x.State == EntityState.Modified).ToList();
here the changeTracker behavior is not consistent.  I am getting Sometime 0 change. Sometime Old value(e.g. rowB even if i make changes to rowC and sometime both (rowB and rowC). I think I am not able to use ChangeTracker Properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

User EF Object Change Tracker. There are two ways Connected and Disconnected mode in Entity Framework. And ObjectChangeTracker Will keep track of your changes in Entities. 
Note: It will make your entity object heavy . So choose what properties you want to keep track of and use those only.